# SQL link to Access database error

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyqt4, pyodbc

I am having an issue with saving some data via SQL to a database. This code worked originally:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=C:\\Users\\george\\Documents\\Homework\\Computing\\Monkey Studio\DrivingSchoolDatabase.accdb')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("insert into Students(Forename,Surname,Address1,Address2,PostCode,Home,Mobile,Email,License,Expiry,Medical,DOB,EyeTest) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",forename,surname,address1,address2,postCode,homePhone,mobilePhone,email,license,expiry,medical,DOB,eyeTest)
        cnxn.commit()
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, 'Saved','Student data saved')
        self.close()
```

I then added two new fields into the access database and added them to the code so I had this (the two new variables are previous and where):

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=C:\\Users\\george\\Documents\\Homework\\Computing\\Monkey Studio\DrivingSchoolDatabase.accdb')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("insert into Students(Forename,Surname,Address1,Address2,PostCode,Home,Mobile,Email,License,Expiry,Medical,DOB,EyeTest,Previous,Where) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",forename,surname,address1,address2,postCode,homePhone,mobilePhone,email,license,expiry,medical,DOB,eyeTest,previous,where)
        cnxn.commit()
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, 'Saved','Student data saved')
        self.close()
```

I now get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\george\Documents\Homework\Computing\Monkey Studio\AddAStudent.py", line 118, in AddCreateStu
cursor.execute("insert into Students(Forename,Surname,Address1,Address2,PostCode,Home,Mobile,Email,License,Expiry,Medical,DOB,EyeTest,Previous,Where) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",forename,surname,address1,address2,postCode,homePhone,mobilePhone,email,license,expiry,medical,DOB,eyeTest,previous,where)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]           Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I'm probably missing something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE` is a SQL keyword, which makes it a poor choice as a field name.  If you can't rename the field, enclose it in square brackets in your `INSERT` statement.

```sql
... Previous,[Where]) values ...
```